# C++ nested class in separated header file

Tags: c++, nested

I would like to move the nested class Inner from Outer.h in a separated header file:

```
class Outer{
    class Inner{
    public:
        Inner(Outer& o){}
    };

public:
    Outer():i(*this){}
    ~Outer(){}
    Inner i;
};
```

And for 'main.cpp'

```
#include "Outer.h"
int main(){
    Outer o;
    return 0;
}
```

But once I try to place Inner class inside a separated header like this:

```
class Outer{
    class Inner;

public:
    Outer():i(*this){}
    ~Outer(){};
    Inner i;
};
```

and place the Inner class in 'Inner.h' like this:

```
class Outer::Inner{
public:
    Inner(Outer& o){}
};
```

and add into the main #include 'Inner.h' like this:

```
#include "Outer.h"
#include "Inner.h"
int main(){
    Outer o;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error from the compiler: Outer.h:10:9: error: field 'i' has incomplete type.

I understand more or less why but I can't find a issue to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create `Outer` object, the memory layout of the class must be known and in this case, it isn't (exactly because of the incompleteness of `Inner`).

The way to do this, is to use a pointer, then the forward declaration will work (as the pointer has fixed size and then the memory layout of `Outer` will be known).

---

What I mean is:

```
// header file
class Outer{
    class Inner;

public:
    Outer();
    ~Outer();

    Inner* i;
};
```

And then, in the source file for class `Outer`, define

```
// include header file for Outer and Inner classes

// source file
Outer::Outer()
{
    i = new Inner( *this );
};
Outer::~Outer()
{
    delete i;
};
```

You need to do this in the source file, because you need to `include` the header file of class `Inner` (you cannot `include` it in the header file directly, because you'll encounter a circular dependency (two header files will include each other), as the header file of `Inner` will also need the header file of `Outer`).

---

This is also known as *pImpl* idiom - "pointer to implementation" and often `Inner` is called `Impl` and the member `pImpl` or something like this, depending on the used coding convention. The idea is to hide any implementation details, like private/protected members (functions, data).

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of `Inner` be visible in order to define `Outer`'s constructor as you did?

Comment: @bou - you're welcome. You should accept some answer, that helped you solving the issue.

Comment: I had to correct a little typo in your answer with the place of '~' for the destructor. Thank you again.

Comment: @KirilKirov Is there any way to do this so that I can do `#include "Outer.h` in my main file instead of `#include "Inner.h` while having `Inner` as a member of `Outer`?

Comment: In the main file, you don't need to include the `Inner`, just the `Outer.h`. The `Inner.h` must be included in the `Outer.cpp` (or in `Outer.h`, depending on the implementation).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to turn your `i` member into a pointer your best option is to move the definition of `Inner` outside of `Outer` and use namespaces for nesting.

Note that in this case you would need to include the `Inner.h` header before `Outer`'s definition.